# Beamer box alignment with enumerate placeholders

Tags: beamer, enumerate, block

I'm trying to align a beamer box with the placeholder of an enumerated environment, but as you can see below it doesn't work out of the box.
So far I've tried to resize the blue box with both with `\resizebox` and `\adjustbox` but neither of them seems to work with a beamer block inside.
I'd like to vertically align the box on the left with the text "Some other text".
I'm not very skilled with beamer (and LaTex in general). Any help?

```
\begin{frame}{FRAME TITLE}
    \begin{enumerate}[Step 1]
        \item
            \begin{theorem}
                My theorem
            \end{theorem}
        \item Some other text
        \item Some other text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the theorem into a `minipage` of `\linewidth` helps:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{FRAME TITLE}
    \begin{enumerate}[Step 1]
        \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                    \vspace*{-1.1\baselineskip}
               \begin{theorem}
                       My theorem
                   \end{theorem}
        \end{minipage}
        \item Some other text
        \item Some other text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just a little inconvenient: in this way the "Step 1" placeholder is placed at half the height of the minipage, is there a way to put it aligned with the the top?

Comment: @Sirion You could try `\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}`

Comment: Unfortunately `[t]` makes the minipage environment start one line below "Step 1".

Comment: @Sirion Please see my edited post